# How can I get my xpath provided by chrome to pull proper text versus an empty string?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape property data on from "http://web6.seattle.gov/DPD/ParcelData/parcel.aspx?pin=9906000005".

I identify the element that I am interested in ("Base Zone" data in the table) and copied the xpath from the chrome developer tool. When I run it through scrapy I get an empty list.

I used the scrapy shell to upload the site and typed several response requests. The page loads and I can scrape the header, but nothing in the body of the page loads, it all comes up as empty lists.

My scrapy script is as follows:

```
class ZoneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'zone'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ['http://web6.seattle.gov/DPD/ParcelData/parcel.aspx? 
pin=9906000005']

def parse(self, response):
    self.log("base_zone: %s" % response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cph_p_i1_i0_vwZoning"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/text()').extract())
    self.log("use: %s" % response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_cph_p_i3_i0_vwKC"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract())
```

You will see that the logs return an empty list.  In the scray shell when I use query the xpath for the header I get a valid response:

> > > response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_headSection"]/title/text()').extract()
> > >       ['\r\n\tSeattle Parcel Data\r\n']

But when I query anything in the body I get an empty list:

> > > response.xpath('/body').extract()
> > >       []

What I would like to see in my scrapy code is a response like the following:

base_zone: "SF 5000"

use: "Duplex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `tbody` from your XPATH it will work

> Since Developer Tools operate on a live browser DOM, what you’ll
>   actually see when inspecting the page source is not the original HTML,
>   but a modified one after applying some browser clean up and executing
>   Javascript code. Firefox, in particular, is known for adding 
>   elements to tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the
>   original page HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you
>   use  in your XPath expressions.

Source: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  Is there anyway to have the page load without browser modifications/ what is the best way to access the original html?